# plot from a large data set into several figures

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have a large set of particle position data from a movie made by a detection camera in a physical experiment. The first column just gives the frame number, the second to fourth column is x, y, and z position.
Now I would like to plot the x and y position for the first 10 frames, but for each frame in a different figure. I'm using the `compress` command to extract the data of each frame. Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import compress

data = np.genfromtxt('beta_tracking.csv', delimiter=' ')

f=data[:,0]
x=data[:,1]
y=data[:,2]
z=data[:,3]

k=range(1,11)
for j in k:
    g=list(compress(x, (abs(i)==j for i in f)))
    h=list(compress(y, (abs(i)==j for i in f)))
    plot(g,h,',')
    savefig('plots/framedata.png')
```

However, this gives me the x and y position for the first 10 frames all in one figure. How can I tell python to make a new figure for each frame and save them automatically?

Comment: `np.loadtxt` is much faster than `np.genfromtxt` and should be usable if your data is only space delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this code does exactly what I was looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from itertools import compress


data = np.genfromtxt('beta_tracking.csv', delimiter=' ')

f=data[:,0]
x=data[:,1]
y=data[:,2]
z=data[:,3]

k=range(1,11)
for j in k:
    g=list(compress(x, (abs(i)==j for i in f)))
    h=list(compress(y, (abs(i)==j for i in f)))
    FigList = [ ] 
    FigList.append(plt.figure())
    ax = FigList[-1].add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(g,h,',')
    for i in plt.get_fignums():
          plt.figure(i)
          plt.savefig('plots/figure%d.png' % i)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html

the OO interface of matplotlib allows you to keep track of where you are plotting your lines, it would be something like this:

```
FigList = [ ] # to store the figures
for x,y in zip(g,h):
    FigList.append(plt.figure())
    ax = FigList[-1].add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(x,y,',')
    FigList[-1].savefig(FigureName)
```